# Laravel multiple parallel requests seems to cause wrong connection to be used

Tags: php, ajax, database, laravel

I'm having a Laravel 5.2 single page app that after rendering in the DOM will fetch some settings via AJAX calls. It is very possible that many ajax calls are done simultaneously.

Sometimes I will receive a 500 error because the table users cannot be found (which does exist). If I extract the query I can see that the used query language is sqlite while my database settings state that it should be sqlsrv. So it seems Laravel is using sqlite as database connection.

Does anyone has any idea on why this happens and what I can do to prevent it?

The database config is:

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
    'acti' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_ACTI_DRIVER', 'sqlite'),
        'host' => env('DB_ACTI_HOST', null),
        'database' => env('DB_ACTI_DATABASE', ':memory:'),
        'username' => env('DB_ACTI_USERNAME', null),
        'password' => env('DB_ACTI_PASSWORD', null),
        'charset' => env('DB_ACTI_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix' => env('DB_ACTI_PREFIX', ''),
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    'aspect' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_ASPECT_DRIVER', 'sqlite'),
        'host' => env('DB_ASPECT_HOST', null),
        'database' => env('DB_ASPECT_DATABASE', ':memory:'),
        'username' => env('DB_ASPECT_USERNAME', null),
        'password' => env('DB_ASPECT_PASSWORD', null),
        'charset' => env('DB_ASPECT_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix' => env('DB_ASPECT_PREFIX', ''),
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    'navision' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_NAVISION_DRIVER', 'sqlite'),
        'host' => env('DB_NAVISION_HOST', null),
        'database' => env('DB_NAVISION_DATABASE', ':memory:'),
        'username' => env('DB_NAVISION_USERNAME', null),
        'password' => env('DB_NAVISION_PASSWORD', null),
        'charset' => env('DB_NAVISION_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix' => env('DB_NAVISION_PREFIX', ''),
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ]
]
```

The ajax code is as follows:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: laroute.route('acti.preference.get', {
                pluginName: this.plugin.name,
                name: this.name
            }),
            success: $.proxy(function (data) {
                this.updateFromApi(data.value);
                if (data.value === undefined) {
                    this.saveToApi();
                }
            }, this),
            error: function () {
                console.log('receive error', arguments);
            }
        })
```

The standard connection is 'acti' and the .env holds the correct information.

After some testing I can confirm that the env method does not always return the correct information. I can see that sometimes the default value (which is sqlite) is returned in stead of the actual data in the .env file.

Comment: Let's see your ajax code, your .env or database config file and finally are you running two apps on the same server?

Comment: I have many Laravel apps on my localhost. But I'm only using this one now. The ajax calls are being done with the standard jQuery: $.ajax() method.

Comment: It almost seems as if there are to many instances running at once the .env file cannot be read and it will use the default value of the env method which in this case is sqlite...

Comment: Have you tried specifying the connection in your User model? `protected $connection = 'acti';`

Comment: Yes I did, but it doesn't seem to affect the behavior, which I think is because the connection is being setup wrongly. The model does use the acti connection, however it is setup as being an sqlite connection (which it shouldn't be)

Comment: Can you update your question with the Ajax code? Perhaps someone can recommend some changes for it. You may be able to manage the calls to the server in a different way. Have you tried explicitly defining the DB in your database config and see if that fixes the issue? I had a similar issue with using the .env file in a multithreaded php version: see discussion here: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/76#issuecomment-87252126

Comment: It indeed looks like a bug in the dotenv library. I'm gonna try to do it with hardcoded values..

Comment: @RickBrunken Did you get it working?

Comment: I did a lot of debuggin on this and found out that the environment was being setup with every api call. If two calls crossed eachother they would both be setting up the environment and one of the two requests would use a not fully setup environment. I did not get it working correctly so I ended up using hardcoded values. I'm not sure if this issue has been fixed in later releases though...